# How can I OCR the text from specific regions of a screenshot, then output that to a usable format?

Tags: spreadsheet, screenshot, ocr

I'm trying to automate logging of uh, ranked games in Street Fighter of all things - Yes, nerdy, I know. I have a spreadsheet [image]

In that I manually put in the following for each ranked game:

1. The opponent's username
2. Their character
3. Their points before the match
4. My points before the match

This isn't a massive deal, but we're on Super User, right? Ideally I'd love to be able to take a screenshot of the screen that shows this information

[image]

Then have those details in some way automatically parsed via OCR, in a way that I can then use further down the line.. somehow. How can I go about doing this? I haven't a clue but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: Try to do the capturing manually first and run that image through OCR. Then, if you have a problem issues with the capturing or with the OCR or the conversion to a spreadsheet, you can post a question on that specific problem, mentioning what you have tried.

Comment: That's no help at all. That's exactly what I'm asking how to do - OCR text from specific portions of screenshots automatically, and output to a usable format.

Comment: The thing is, you are asking many different things at once, without providing any previous research. I was just trying to help you narrow down the problem. It is not clear if you don't know how to capture, do the OCR o postprocess the OCR output. Usually questions are about something specific and people show what they've tried. If you ask things that way, you will probably get answers, otherwise it is more difficult, because the somebody that could help you out with OCR does no necessarily know how to make an automatic screen capture.

Comment: What spreadsheet software are you using? Have you checked the game publisher to see if they have a public API for this data? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Of course I know how do take a screenshot Eduardo, there's one right there in the post, and it's clear that I want to process specific parts of those screenshots using OCR software, while being unaware of how to do so yet. That's what the entire post is about.

Burgi, hi! At the moment it's on Sheers, but Excel would be fine too - no real preference either way. While it'd be great if there were another way to get this info via an API or such, it's only available on this screen ingame (and in another place, also ingame). I've had a look at tesseract, Capture2Text and UiPath.

Answer (score 0):

There are many utilities that do OCR. Below are some possibilities:

- [Greenshot for Windows](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot) is my personal
  favorite.
- Microsoft's OneNote will try to OCR imported pictures
- [Capture2Text](https://sourceforge.net/projects/capture2text/)
- [FreeOCR](http://www.paperfile.net/index.html)
- [Photo to Text OCR](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/photo-to-text-ocr/9nblggh6hrzh?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

But you may find many others via Google.